# How do you say "grumpy" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, word-choice

I would like to say, "I am a grumpy dog," since I did not get my proper sleep last night. I have a few guesses about "grumpy", but these are only guesses. I looked up "grumpy" on Whitaker's words and found nothing. I looked up ["irritable"](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?english=irritable) and found *stomachosus* as well as *acriculus*.

> Stomachosus canis sum. / Acriculus canis sum.

I wanted to know if either of these words are *le mot juste*. If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with *stomachosus*, though it is not a very common word. Smith recommends, besides *stomachosus*, *difficilis*:

> II. In partic., of character, hard to manage or to please, obstinate, captious, morose, surly: “difficiles ac morosi,” Cic. Or. 29 fin.; “moderati nec difficiles nec inhumani senes,” Cic. de Sen. 3, 7: “sunt morosi et anxii et iracundi et difficiles senes,” id. ib. 18, 65

That last reference also gives us *iracundus*:

> I.irascible, irritable, passionate, choleric, angry, ireful, easily provoked (class.): “iratus potest non esse iracundus: iracundus non potest aliquando iratus non esse, Sen. de Ira, 1, 4, 1 (al. om. non before potest): ut non tantum iratus sit sapiens, sed iracundus,” id. ib. 2, 6, 3: “sunt morosi et anxii et iracundi senes,” Cic. de Sen. 18, 65: “iracundum esse in aliquem,” id. Planc. 26, 63: “adversus hostes,” Just. 7, 6, 15: “quemadmodum posset leniri, Sen. de Ira, 1, 1, 1: tale non est ira, sed quasi ira,” id. ib. 1, 2, 6: “leones,” Ov. M. 15, 86: “mens,” Lucr. 3, 296.—Comp.: “iracundior est paulo,” Hor. S. 1, 3, 29.—Sup.: iracundissimus, Sen. de Ira, 2, 6, 4; 2, 15, 1.

*Acriculus* is [*only* found](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=acricul) in Cicero's *Tusculanae Disputationes*, so personally I'd stay away from it, especially with *iracundus* paralleling *grumpy* so neatly.

Answer (score 5):

In my first year of Latin in high school, we read a much simplified version of [Querolus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querolus), about a very grumpy old man and his pot o' gold. It turns out to be post-classical, probably 5th century, but it tries to use classical vocabulary and style.

The word `Querolus` itself translates more directly to something like "the complainer", but it's quite close to what you seem to need (although it's a substantive). If you read the [source text](http://digiliblt.lett.unipmn.it/xtf/view?query=;brand=default;docId=dlt000432/dlt000432.xml;), then maybe there will be some interesting synonyms there.